# Why am I forced to log in?

Tags: 8

I'm a long-time Drupal 7developer, and tried a Drupal 8 install yesterday for evaluation. I installed a bunch of contrib modules. All seems ok, but when I go to the home page, I'm presented with a login screen. I want anonymous users to be able to see the site, how can I allow this? I don't see any settings to force login, and am not using the shield module.

Comment: What is the front page set to at Admin -> Configuration -> System -> Basic Site Settings? Set it to `/node` if it's empty.

Comment: This is not standard behavior of a default install. Something within "I installed a bunch of contrib modules" is likely the culprit.

Comment: I think the login block is often on the page by default. My guess is the front page is empty and all you're seeing is the login block.

Comment: Simply restart with a fresh standard installation. Check if everything's fine. Then add modules one by one. Until the error occurs. But most likely you simply have left the default front page to be empty at /admin/config/system/site-information.

Answer (score 0):

D8 default front page is a view page `admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit/page_1`. Views in 7 and 8/9 is quite similar from a end user perspective meaning you should feel right at home. D7 and 8 default front page is /node as you see and normal access permission.

[image: Drupal 9 front page view]

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. Figured it out.